# gcc accepts and clang rejects this code with nested generic lambdas, why?

Tags: c++, lambda, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

According to Godbolt's Compiler Explorer (see [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aq4jhe)), the following code compiles with GCC (both 10.2 and trunk) and outputs 3628800, but fails to compile with Clang (both 11.0.1 and trunk). In both cases, `-std=c++17` is used. It also compiles with MSVC 19, but not with other compilers. Why is that and whose behavior is correct?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << [](auto f) { return f(f); }(
        [](auto& h) {
            return [&h](auto n) {
                if (n < 2)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return n * h(h)(n - 1);
                };
            })(10) << std::endl;
}
```

Further, even GCC and MSVC reject the code if I replace `auto n` with `int n` or if I replace if-else with the ternary operator (`return n < 2 ? 1 : (n * h(h)(n - 1));`).

Comment: You may need to read an entire book about typed lambda calculus

Comment: You should add a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/noEKex) to the question. Also, you can compile with MSVC19 on godbolt. Also, you should mention the language version (I assume C++17). Also, please format that code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch if you have some specific book in mind, please recommend

Comment: @cigien done as you suggested

Comment: Thank you, that's much better. I've edited the question a bit, take a look at the edit message. Also, this is not necessary, but questions about compiler variance are often tagged with [language-lawyer] since they almost by definition, need to be answered by quoting the standard. You might want to consider adding that tag.

Comment: Start with this book: [*Types and programming languages*](https://dlhoyt.com/types_and_programming_languages_benjamin_c_pierce.pdf) (Pierce). Also read about [*Categories and computer science*](https://www.amazon.com/Categories-Computer-Science-Cambridge-Texts/dp/0521422264)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This program is ill-formed, **no diagnostic required**, so both implementations (indeed, *any* implementation) are correct.  The rule violated is [temp.res.general]/6.4:

> a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter

The template here is the innermost `operator()`: it uses the specialization of the immediately containing `operator()` (with the very closure type of which it is a member as a template argument), which has a deduced return type.  "Immediately following" here is (still) within the very return statement from which that type shall be deduced, so the instantiation would be ill-formed due to just `h(h)`, which does not involve a template parameter of *that* template (*i.e.*, the type of `n`).

GCC and MSVC don't bother doing the semantic check for the deduced return type until the final instantiation (with `int` for the 10), by which point the return type is known: it's just the appropriate variant of the innermost lambda.  If that innermost lambda is not generic, however, the check takes place **during** instantiation of the containing `operator()`, and the same error occurs.

This difference of behavior can be seen in a much simpler example:

```
auto g();
template<class T> auto f(T x) {return g()-x;}
```

Clang has already rejected at this point, but GCC accepts, perhaps followed by

```
auto g() {return 1;}
int main() {return f(1);}
```